# SQL Alter Procedure not working with Set Quoted_Identifier Off

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I am trying to update and I have added the following lines of code to it:

```
DECLARE @Yesterday date = GETDATE () - 1;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
DECLARE @YesterdayString varchar(20) = ("'" + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Yesterday,110) + "'");
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

When I try to alter the procedure, I get an error message saying:

```
Invalid column name '''.
```

The query runs fine when I execute it, I just can't make the changes to the procedure.  Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: what output or string you want to append or  do you want can please elaborate

Comment: This code runs fine.

Comment: It does not run in an alter or create procedure script

Comment: [`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174393.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): "When executed inside a stored procedure, the setting of SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is not changed." Although from the sample given, it's difficult to tell what you actually thought it was going to change anyway.

Comment: Ok that is helpful to know.  I removed it from inside the stored procedure and turned it off outside the alter statement and that worked.  Thanks.